# How to display two line traffic road map cartographically?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cartography, symbology, representation

I have two line traffic maps. I want to display these maps roads as image below. These images show that when I zoom out from map, roads are showing properly.. And two line road never disappear from map. And when I zoom in map, other roads appear properly and two line. How can I do that this trick with ESRI solutions ?

Example - http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=30c24162643b43c291c8151b24674c7f

I follow ESRI's representation tutorials from [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/cartographic-representations-tutorial.pdf) but I could not get this view.

**EDIT 1** - 
All I want to do is show 2 lines of road every scale. For viewing every scale width of road may be changeable.

[image]

[image: Details Map]
[image: Two Line Show Map]

Comment: from the site that you take as an illustration, I am pretty sure that the two lines exist in the database as separate lines (because the distance between lines is not constant). Do you have double lines or single lines in your case?

Comment: I have double lines too but my lines become one part when i zoom out from map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had no way to go then I would have followed below steps-

Say these layers are line feature (for other same procedure)-

```
1. Edit symbol.
2. Change Line Type to "Cartographic Line Symbol" and set line "Width" 3 for all three(my case) layers.
3. Go to "Line Properties" tab and set offset properly( I have three layers so I offsetted "Layer1" by +3 "Layer2"  by 0 and "Layer3" by -3).
4. Click on the "Full Extent" button record the scale (for me it is 1:350).
5. Go to "General" Tab in the "Data frame" windows and set "Reference Scale" to that sacle (for me it is 1:350).
```

Now you are ready to go.

[image: Representation]

Comment: Thank you great man. You did like a monster. You save our lots of day. Thanks.. thanks.. thanks.. Wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve this visualization in an ArcMap Desktop application or a web map?

In ArcGIS you can put these different categories of roads on separate layers. In the Layer Properties you can set that a layer only displays at certain scales. So you can adjust your layer with the smaller one line roads to not display above a certain zoom (out) level.

[image: Displaying layers at certain scales]

See an instruction here at the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000008000000)

**EDIT 1:**

To get the two line symbology you need to double-click you line symbol in your table of contents in ArcMap. On the left you can then choose a preset symbol if you have some symbology libraries installed (ESRI has some standard symbols for highways that might fit your needs) or you click to edit the symbol on the right side of the window. There you can create symbols that have more than one layer which is what you need in your case. Think of your road symbol not as two lines but as three lines on top of each other: a thick black line with a slightly thinner green linie on top with a thin black line on top.

You can find help on creating symbols here in the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000004000000)

**EDIT 2:**

For the symbology of two lines with different colours next to each other you need to have a symbol with two layers and give one line the type "Cartographic Line Symbol". Then you can specify an offset for that line.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My aim is not only showing roads some scales but also showing two line every scale size. I'm gonna edit my question to show another hint to make my question understandable. :)

Comment: Ok I see. I just edited the answer.

Comment: But yellow line and orange line are different lines. Think about the line passes through bridge. left side and right side  has  different line. When i zoom out from the map, this two line becoming one for view. I want to this two lines should show seperately. Hope I could tell.

Comment: To be honest I do not completely understand your problem. Best is you show some visual examples of what exactly you imagine including special behaviours at bridges etc. Keep in mind even though you have two layers in the symbology your line symbol still refers to the same single line featuer in the map. But I am still not sure if that is actually what you want.

Comment: I gived one link at the top.when zoom out  inside this world traffic map roads not become one part. everytime it seperate two part.    

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=30c24162643b43c291c8151b24674c7f

Comment: The roads on the map you linked actually DO get displayed as single lines if you zoom out far enough. So do you want this map service to display differently (which might not be possible)? Or do you want to create something like this with your own data?

Comment: I want to create something like this with my own data. My linked map shows two line roads. Not single line. 

Here screenshot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/mwnAE.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20378/discussion-between-salihy-and-chris-p).

Answer (score 0):

Cartographic representation in ArcGIS will allow you to do this.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000004m000000

Not the most straight-forward, but gives you lots of control if you're willing to work out all the details.

Comment: I faced with cartographic representetion. I have one question about it. Cortagrographic representation can be store within style. But my layer has dynamic style.Think about traffic density map. Whenever traffic density change my style change too. So when I use the representation, my style become static. Do you think I could use representation without style ?

Comment: I see now. As far as I know, representations are not intended to be rendered based on dynamic input. Perhaps it would be possible to use Python to script automatic re-definition of the style representation at given intervals or triggers, but I have not seen anything like that.